# solving a set of vector equations

Tags: vector-spaces

Let's have six vectors $\boldsymbol p$, $\boldsymbol r$, $\boldsymbol s$, $\boldsymbol t$, $\boldsymbol u$, $\boldsymbol v$ from $\mathbb{R}^N$. We are given the following two vector equations:

$$a_1 \boldsymbol{p}+a_2\boldsymbol{r} = \boldsymbol{u}\\
a_1 \boldsymbol{s}+a_2\boldsymbol{t} = \boldsymbol{v}$$

How do I get the two scalars $a_1$ and $a_2$? I tried to multiply each equation by some vector to solve this in projection but this does not seem to work very well, because I may accidentally pick a projection to which one of the vectors is orthogonal.

I should emphasize that my system contains many more than 2 equations and I generally do not want to find this solution "by hand". I am looking for a suitable numerical scheme to solve this.

Comment: I count six vectors $p,r,s,t,u,v$... Also assuming no further relations on the vectors, the two equations can be solved separately, neither is dependent on the other.

Comment: Corrected. Sure, I can express $a_1$ from the first, substitute it into the second, get $a_2$ and then also $a_1$ from the first. However, I have a system of tens of equations like this and I need to do this in computer - looking for a numerical method.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I overlooked the fact that $a_1$ and $a_2$appear in both equations. My answer still holds though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no further restrictions on the vectors, your two vector equations yield an (overdetermined) system of linear equations. Letting

$$\vec{p} = (p_1, ..., p_N), \\\vec{r} = (r_1, ..., r_N), \\\vec{u} = (u_1, ..., u_N)$$

and similarly for $\vec{s},\vec{t},\vec{v}$

we get the system

$$\begin{align*}
a_1 p_1 + a_2 r_1 &= u_1 \\
a_1 p_2 + a_2 r_2 &= u_2 \\
&\vdots \\
a_1p_N + a_2 r_N &= u_N \\
a_1s_1 + a_2 t_1 &= v_1 \\
&\vdots \\
a_1s_N + a_2 t_N &= v_N \\
\end{align*}
$$

which is usually solved by Gaussian elimination or something similar. If the system is inconsistent, QR decomposition will give a least squares approximation.

It doesn't matter how many vector equations you have, each will just contribute $N$ more equations to the system. Any linear algebra library or program will have methods to solve linear systems.

Comment: Thanks Josh. I was thinking of this but my $N$ can be very large and this may take a lot of time. I can write the two vector equations in components, which will (as you say) give me $2N$ linear algebraic equations for 2 unknown values of $a_1$ and $a_2$. The least-squares solution of the system $\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{b}$ is then $\boldsymbol{x}=(\boldsymbol{A}^T\boldsymbol{A})^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}^T \boldsymbol{b}$.

Comment: Isn't there another trick to solve this problem without doing the matrix multiplication?

Comment: Is this for some kind of computer program? In your question you asked for a suitable "numerical scheme", I'm not entirely sure what you mean otherwise. Computer linear algebra systems will usually allow you to input the system and just call a function to solve it, no need to go multiplying matrices yourself.